# Error in jquery does not display FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, fullcalendar

Make the insertion of the code as the official documentation of the FullCalendar says but at the time of running the page does not show me the calendar.
[imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXwVk.jpg)

I think the error can be to a script that I attached on my web these are all I work with.

```
     <!-- calendar -->
        <link href='temporal/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <link href='temporal/fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
        <script src='temporal/moment.min.js'></script>
        <script src='temporal/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='temporal/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>


        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-responsive.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vertical-rhythm.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/push.min.js"></script>

            <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2017-05-12',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2017-05-01'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2017-05-07',
                    end: '2017-05-10'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2017-05-09T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2017-05-16T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Conference',
                    start: '2017-05-11',
                    end: '2017-05-13'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2017-05-12T10:30:00',
                    end: '2017-05-12T12:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: '2017-05-12T12:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2017-05-12T14:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Happy Hour',
                    start: '2017-05-12T17:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Dinner',
                    start: '2017-05-12T20:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2017-05-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2017-05-28'
                }
            ]
        });

    });

</script>
            <style type="text/css">
            #calendar {
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;

    }
            </style>

<div id="calendar"></div>

        <!-- JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.localScroll.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.viewport.mini.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.appear.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAZsDkJFLS0b59q7cmW0EprwfcfUA8d9dg"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gmap3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.simple-text-rotator.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact-form.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Link All the Calender Js Below `jquery-1.11.2.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

Modify Your code like this

```
<!-- calendar -->
    <link href='temporal/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='temporal/fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />



    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vertical-rhythm.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">        



        <style type="text/css">
        #calendar {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;

}
        </style>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.localScroll.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.viewport.mini.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.appear.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAZsDkJFLS0b59q7cmW0EprwfcfUA8d9dg"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gmap3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.simple-text-rotator.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact-form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js"></script>  
    <script src='temporal/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='temporal/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/push.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2017-05-12',
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2017-05-01'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2017-05-07',
                end: '2017-05-10'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2017-05-09T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2017-05-16T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Conference',
                start: '2017-05-11',
                end: '2017-05-13'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2017-05-12T10:30:00',
                end: '2017-05-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: '2017-05-12T12:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2017-05-12T14:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Happy Hour',
                start: '2017-05-12T17:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Dinner',
                start: '2017-05-12T20:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: '2017-05-13T07:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2017-05-28'
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

Comment: Call the code at the end and I get these new errors.

Comment: call these URLs above all JS in picture

Comment: Check edits, jquery.min.js were called twice, and try to put inline JS at bottom most